# How to use print queue to send a collection of visuals for printing?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, printing

I have an array of parameters which will command the UI to change. Currently, for each array parameter, I am changing my UI and sending the UI as a visual for printing. But now, I need to send the visuals all at a time to the printer. In other words, I have 10 pages and sending each page for printing. I need to send all the 10 pages at a time to printer so as to support duplex printing. I think I can do this by using PrintQueue. But not sure how to use it. Hope some one can help me on this.

```
private void ButtonPrintAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
  //Creating the print dialog 
  //Show print Dialog 
  if(printDialog.ShowDialog()) 
  { 
     for(int i = 0; i < arrayParameterts.Count; i++)
     { 
        frmMainContent.Source = new Uri(arrayParameterts[i], UriKind.Relative);
        frmMainContent.UpdateLayout(); 
     } 
  } 
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: can you perhaps paste the code that you have and maybe there is a way someone can see how to accomplish this based on seeing your existing logic. in your code do you have any reference to Duplex for example Printer.Duplex = 2 Printer.Print "Testing Page 1

Comment: Here is the blocks of code I am using for printing.In the button click,I'll get the array of parameters and I am changing the source of the Frame in the WPF page with different user controls depending on the array parameter:
<pre class="prettyprint">
private void ButtonPrintAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  //Creating the print dialog
  //Show print Dialog
  if(printDialog.ShowDialog())
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayParameterts.Count; i++)
    {
     frmMainContent.Source = new Uri(arrayParameterts[i], UriKind.Relative);
     frmMainContent.UpdateLayout();
    }
  }
}</pre>

Comment: In the frame rendered event, I am printing the layout as a visual


void frmMainContent_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Get the printer capbilities
   PrintCapabilities printerCapabilities = printDialog.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(pDialog.PrintTicket);
   //Print the visual
   printDialog.PrintVisual(this, "My Printouts");
}

I am sending one print out at a time. So, the printer is not printing in duplex. I need to send them at once so that the prints two sides of the page. I am sorry for all the bad formatting. I am new and not sure how I can do the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[how to change printer to print Duplex](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Print-on-both-sides-of-a-sheet-of-paper-duplex-e070b1f9-f532-40f0-8651-2ee3f2de9fb1)
This site explains what an individual did to correct all of the bad examples that were out on the web.. this should help you to get started or convert your existing code over..

I would create a method that works extract that method to an Interface and create another method for Duplex and extract it to an Interface that way if you want to have your code toggle between batch style printing or print duplex.. then you can configure it to handle that. no need to waste good code hope this helps